# Forest Trust Relationship and DNS

Tags: active-directory, internal-dns, dns-zone, trust-relationship

I am creating a new single domain Forest, SCP.com  and I have an existing single domain Forest, ICS.com

Have an existing internal DNS server in ICS.com that has a Forward Lookup Zone for the domain SCP.com pointing to a handful of web applications that live in the ICS.com domain, but with the SCP.com doman name registration under that Forward Lookup Zone.

If I create a 2 WAY Transitive Trust between the ICS.com and SCP.com Forests, I will need to create Conditional forwarders between the two domains:

- ICS.com will have a conditional forwarder to SCP.com
- SCP.com will have a conditional forwarder to ICS.com

How will the Conditional Forwarder to SCP.com IN the ICS.com DNS server affect the existing Forward Look Up Zone for SCP.com ( already in use on the ICS.com DNS server) ?

Will the Foward Look Up Zone settings only apply to the manually added entries?

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to have conditional forwarder to scp.com when ics.com already hosts (is authoritative) for scp.com?

- if scp zone in ICS domain is secondary, then you are all set, you don't need conditional forwarding;
- If scp zone in ICS domain is primary, then you can't have 2 authoritative sources for same zone. Migrate all scp.com records that are hosted within ics.com to DNS in scp.com domain, and remove the duplicate zone from ics.com. After that you can either make it secondary zone or use only conditional forwarding